# What is the limit of validity for WKB expansion for black hole Quasi-normal modes?

Tags: black-holes, semiclassical, normal-modes

Which is the limit of validity for WKB expansion for black hole Quasi-normal modes? In many papers I see that the authors only report the overtone $n=1$. Is WKB expansion valid only for small $n$?

As an example I refer to [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0303052v6) paper, but I could cite more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer my self in [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.4014) paper, were the author a pag 10 says:

> The higher order WKB approach proved to be useful for finding lower
>   overtones of the quasi normal specrtum and is in  good agreement with
>   accurate numerical data

So yes the WKB approach is accurate only for small n